# Using JasperReports with datasources which rely on CDI

Tags: jasper-reports, cdi

I have some classes which use CDI injected beans in their getters, e.g.:

```
class MyBean() {
    @Inject
    private TranslationBean translationBean;

    private String chosenValue;

    public void setChosenValue(String c) { chosenValue = c;}
    public String getChosenValue() {
        return translationBean.getTranslatedValue(chosenValue);
    }
}
```

The underlying `chosenValue` is loaded from and persisted into a database.

Now I want to create a JasperReport generated PDF with such beans as `DataSource`. I call:

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport("myFile.jasper", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Arrays.asList(myBean));
```

Obviously, the error message from Weld will eventually be that no context is active.

I now see two possibilities:

1. create a wrapping class for `MyBean` especially for JasperReports in which all needed fields are filled with actual data and no CDI dependencies are needed. Problem would be: a LOT of coding with a lot of boilerplate and repeating code.
2. Somehow manage to wrap a context around the call to the `JasperFillManager` so it runs within an/the current active CDI context.

Would the second option be possible? Is there any other, nicer way than one of the proposed ones?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking at creating a new scope, if its possible to wrap all the JasperStuff. Take a look at the Seam Reports stuff in https://github.com/seam/reports, it may be of some help or inspiration.